# Rust wasm-bindgen struct with string

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to export the following struct:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub enum TokenType {
    KeywordLiteral,
    NumberLiteral,
    Operator,
    Separator,
    StringLiteral,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Token {
    pub typ: TokenType,
    pub val: String,
}
```

but I'm getting:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `token::TokenType: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src\tokenizer\token.rs:17:14
   |
14 | #[wasm_bindgen]
   | --------------- required by this bound in `__wbg_get_token_typ::assert_copy`
...
17 |     pub typ: TokenType,
   |              ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `token::TokenType`
```

as well as:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  --> src\tokenizer\token.rs:18:14
   |
14 | #[wasm_bindgen]
   | --------------- required by this bound in `__wbg_get_token_val::assert_copy`
...
18 |     pub val: String,
```

I can add `#[derive(Copy)]` to `TokenType` but not to `String`.

I'm new to rust so help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [wasm-bindgen#1985](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1985), public fields of structs are required to be `Copy` in order for the automatically generated accessors to function.

You can either make the fields private, or annotate them with `#[wasm_bindgen(skip)]`, and then implement a getter and setter directly.

There is an [example provided](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-rust-exports/getter-and-setter.html) in wasm-bindgen's docs describing how to write these:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct Baz {
    field: i32,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl Baz {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new(field: i32) -> Baz {
        Baz { field }
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn field(&self) -> i32 {
        self.field
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen(setter)]
    pub fn set_field(&mut self, field: i32) {
        self.field = field;
    }
}
```

When objects are shared between wasm and js, the js object only contains the pointer to the struct inside the wasm runtime's memory. When you access fields from JS, it goes through a defined property which makes a function call to the wasm code asking it for the property value (you can think of the wasm memory as a bit `UInt8Array`).

Requiring the objects to be `Copy` is probably done to avoid surprises when auto-generating these getters and setters. If you implement them manually, you can have the same behaviour in JS and be able to control what's being set on the rust side.

Comment: So it's not possible to simply have a `String` in a struct?

Comment: And how will that compile to typescript?

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify. You are free to have strings in structs, these just can't be `pub` if you want to use the auto-generated accessors.

Comment: So you are telling me I can have a getter and setter but not directly expose a `String` to JavaScript?

Comment: Ah I just read through your post again. I see, this is pretty cool, although the issue is that rust really limits what I can actually return from wasm. E.g. I want to return a list of tokens but rust simply does not allow vectors to be returned (even though they behave really similar to JS Arrays). So currently my code is serialized via serd and thus copied anyway.

Comment: If you have the time, you could take a look at another one of my questions, would be highly appreciated :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68245335/webpack-and-babel-import-javascript-module-unexpected-token-import

Comment: Vectors aren't suppored but [`Box<[JsValue]>`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/boxed-jsvalue-slice.html) is, and you can use [`Vec::into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) to convert it from a `Vec<JsValue>`, which you get from the wasm-bindgen generated From impl, using something like `.map(JsValue::from)`.